# Are there any methods which accelate Hadamard product?

Tags: matrix, julia, calculation

I think the simplest way to perform the Hadamard product is using ".*", but this code slows down as the matrix grows, becoming a bottleneck in my entire program.

```
a = ones(1000000,1000)
b = ones(1000000,1).*2
a.*b
```

Are there any methods which accelate my program ?

Comment: Is it a one time operation or are you doing this in a loop? If in a loop, are the matrices the same size every time, or different?

Comment: There's no way you can avoid the operation slowing down as the matrices grow, that is a given. But there may be ways to speed it up, if give a bit more context.

Comment: As you mentioned, I am encountering issues due to using the Hadamard product term within a loop. In my situation, 'a' represents a fixed dataset(i.e. there is no difference within loop), while 'b' is a parameter that gets updated within the loop. Since 'b' is different for each iteration of the loop, I need to calculate the Hadamard product every time.

Comment: The more important question is: what happens to the _result_ of the computation? `a .* b` creates a new block of memory. Can you instead _re-use_ that piece of memory, you will save a lot of time on allocations. Also, how do you update `b`? Can you re-use that memory too?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the [Strided.jl](https://github.com/Jutho/Strided.jl) package, which implements multithreaded broadcasting:

```
@strided a .* b
```

(launch julia with `-t <n threads>`)